# Excel VBA Custom Sequence

Tags: excel, vba

Using Excel VBA, I am trying to create a custom sequence.  How can I continue a custom sequence for a range of IP Addresses ranging from: 10.168.187.0 - 10.168.187.100?

The code I have so far is posted below.

```
Sub Sequence()
'
' Sequence Macro
' Macro recorded 13/02/2013 by Don
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+M
'
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "10.168.187.0"
Range("A2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "10.168.187.1"
Range("A3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "10.168.187.2"
Range("A4").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Formula: `="10.168.187." & ROW()-1` (starting in A1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're looking to automate the completion of the cells, the following should work:

```
Sub CompleteRange()

For i = 1 To 101

    Cells(i, 1) = "10.168.187." & (i - 1)

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Dom that has worked exactly how need it. I'm very new to VBA so appreciate the help :)