# How to autocomplete an id_(number) sequence in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a worksheet that will contain data points that identify an item and a category: id1_age, id2_age, id3_age...

For example: [chart example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNFEI.png)

However, I need to create a chart with "p100_category" for different categories, so I'd like to know if there's a way to autocomplete the series as with a normal numerical series.

Comment: I found a similar thread where they use this code https://stackoverflow.com/a/14864498/6556964 
But I don't how to make the sequence number to be harcored in the middle, like: p[num]_category

Comment: Awesome! it worked perfectly. It's the first time I try to attempt something like this. Thank you